# Problem when passing props using history.push() in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

I'm trying to pass props to another component in React using history.push().
My code looks like this:

```
 history.push({pathname:`/tickets/solveticket`,
                state:{ticket:this.props.ticketInfo, user:this.props.currentUser}}); 


 window.location.reload()
```

history is exported like this:

```
 import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

and my route configuration:

```
 import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch,Link } from "react-router-dom"; 
    <Router history={history}> 
    ... <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />


                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

`

and component that renders on /tickets/solveticket url takes history parameters like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
       ticketToSolve:this.props.location.state.ticket,
       currentUser:this.props.location.state.user
    }
}
```

and yet I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ticket' of undefined

I tried to wrap everything in withRouter and it still doesn't work. I also tried using this.props.history.push instead of exported history but in that case my history is not recognized..I've been googling for a day and run out of ideas what could I try, so if anyone has any idea please just write it down..thanks in advance :)

Comment: try adding a check like this ticketToSolve:this.props.location.state.ticket && this.props.location.state.ticket for user also same way try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
       ticketToSolve:"",
       currentUser:""
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
 if(this.props.location.state){
  this.setState({
       ticketToSolve:this.props.location.state.ticket,
       currentUser:this.props.location.state.user
    })
  }
}
```

Because some time you cant be so sure that variables are already set. Might be react render this code first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the values via 'history.push' like:

```
history.push(`/tickets/solveticket`, {
  ticket:this.props.ticketInfo, 
  user:this.props.currentUser
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Rajan's answer solved my issue,but thanks anyway :)